# Quiero que mi base de datos elimine datos despues de 30 dias de haber sido guardados SQL - RAZOR

Tags: c#, razor

(Uso RAZOR)Lo que necesito es que mi base de datos elimine ROWS creados hace 30 dias atras, la fecha de creación la estoy guardando en un campo tipo Datetime. Hasta el momento solo puedo restar y obtener la direfencia de dias, por ejemplo:

```
var Fecha = solicitud.fechainicio - DateTime.Now;
```

de esta manera obtengo la diferencia de dias horas y minutos entre la inserción y la fecha actual. pero a la hora de intentar que se ejecute algún tipo de codigo mediante `@if(Fecha>=30){AQUI IRIÁ LA SENTENCIA SQL PARA ELIMINAR.}`

Me salta el siguiente error:

`El operador '>=' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo 'System.TimeSpan' y 'int`'

Comment: Para tus necesidades lo optimo es hacerlo desde base de datos ( si tu base de datos permite hacerlo), te invito a que investiges como funcionan los jobs y crear uno que basicamente sea una consulta tipo "delete from tabla where tabla.fecha < datetime.now.adddays(-30)" que se lanze una vez al dia por ejemplo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No puedes operar con tipos diferentes, es decir, no puedes comparar un `TimeSpan` y un `int`, para hacerlo debes convertir los 2 en el mismo tipo.

Usando el siguiente código `TotalDays` te está devolviendo un tipo `double` que puedes comparar con el `30`:

```
@if((DateTime.Now - Fecha).TotalDays >= 30){ CÓDIGO }
```

La resta de 2 tipos `DateTime` siempre devuelve un tipo [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) y no un `DateTime` como es de esperar.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Sería interesante especificar que la resta de 2 DateTime en C# da como resultado un `TimeSpan`,no un `DateTime` :